# Javascript click event handler - how do I get the reference to the clicked item?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, click

My HTML:

```
<div id="x" onclick="clickHandler(event)">
   <div id="button1">This turns green</div>
   <div id="button2">This turns blue</div>
</div>
```

So first of all, why am I supposed to be passing "event" into the click handler and is event some kind of system keyword? 
Also, since the click handler is identified on the container div, how do I know which button has been clicked?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`event` is an Event object which is created automatically when an event is fired. Note that you don't have to call it `event` (I tend to call it simply `e`). That Event object has a number of properties which describe the event it represents. In this case, the one you're interested in would be `target`, which shows the element that was the source of the event:

```
function clickHandler(e) {
    var target = e.target;
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/LGmEp/6/).

Unfortunately, it's never quite that simple. While the specification says it should be `event.target`, Internet Explorer likes to be different, and chooses to use `event.srcElement`, so you probably want to put in a check to make sure `event.target` exists! For example:

```
function clickHandler(e) {
    var target = (e.target) ? e.target : e.srcElement;
}
```

Comment: Ahh cool, so target gets me the name of the element that is being clicked on? What is this JFiddle thing btw, mad cool!

Comment: Not the name, it gets you a reference to the actual element itself. And yeah, jsfiddle is a great tool for experimenting and testing quick bits of JS!

Comment: Got a bit confused here. So, yes, `event` is the name of the variable containing an Event object representing the event in an onclick handler. It's a sort of reserved variable name, like `this`.

Comment: Kind of a late comment, but one thing I noticed is that if you use e.getAttribute("id")  the results can vary.  I have an image with an id wrapped in a div with an id, and the event handler is attached to the div using its class selector.  When I click on the image the event.target is the image, and when I click on the div (outside of the image), then the event target is the div, which might be a problem sometimes.  If I use this.getAttribute("id") I always get the id of the div, regardless of whether I clicked on the image or the div.

Answer (score 11):

I usually just name the clicked element in the argument list of the call to the click handler, something like (untested) this:

```
<div id="x">
   <div id="button1" onclick="handle_click_event( this, 'green' )">This turns green</div>
   <div id="button2" onclick="handle_click_event( this, 'blue' )">This turns blue</div>
</div>

function handle_click_event ( obj, new_color ) {
  obj.style.backgroundColor = new_color;
}
```

Could that approach work for you?

Comment: "self" usually refer to the current Window. Therefore, it will not work. Use "this" keyword instead of "self".

Comment: Since it said untested, I tested it via fiddle for you. No, it doesn't work... Here are the changes I had to make for it to work
`function handle_click_event ( new_color ) {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = new_color;
}
<div id="button1" onclick="handle_click_event( 'green' )">This turns green</div>
<div id="button2" onclick="handle_click_event( 'blue' )">This turns blue</div>`

Answer (score -16):

Why can't you do this?

```
<div id="x">
   <div id="button1" onclick="clickHandler1()">This turns green</div>
   <div id="button2" onclick="clickHandler2()">This turns blue</div>
</div>
```

Comment: 'cause this would take a function for each "button" element?