# javascript, calculator error?

Tags: javascript, calculator

i m new to javascript and i m trying to build a calculator using javascript.

```
<form name="calc">
    <div class="screen"><input name="output" class="editscreen"></div>
    <div class="main-keys">
        <button name="del" value="" onClick="rundel()" class="btn2 btn-del">DEL</button>
        <button name="7" value="7" onClick="run7()" class="btn2 num">7</button>
        <button name="8" value="8" onClick="run8()" class="btn2 num">8</button>
        <button name="9" value="9" onClick="run9()" class="btn2 num">9</button>
        <button name="ac" value="ac" onClick="runac()" class="btn2 btn-ac">AC</button>
        <button name="minus" value="-" onClick="runminus()" class="btn2 btn-minus">-</button>
        <button name="4" value="4" onClick="run4()" class="btn2 num">4</button>
        <button name="5" value="5" onClick="run5()" class="btn2 num">5</button>
        <button name="6" value="6" onClick="run6()" class="btn2 num">6</button>
        <button name="multi" value="x" onClick="runmulti()" class="btn2 btn-multi">x</button>
        <button name="plus" value="+" onClick="runplus()" class="btn2 btn-plus">+</button>
        <button name="1" value="1" onClick="run1()" class="btn2 num">1</button>
        <button name="2" value="2" onClick="run2()" class="btn2 num">2</button>
        <button name="3" value="3" onClick="run3()" class="btn2 num">3</button>
        <button name="div" value="÷" onClick="rundiv()" class="btn2 btn-div">÷</button>
        <button name="ans" value="ans" onClick="runans()" class="btn2 btn-ans">ANS</button>
        <button name="0" value="0" onClick="run0()" class="btn2 num">0</button>
        <button name="dec" value="." onClick="rundec()" class="btn2 num">.</button>
        <button name="exp" value="exp" onClick="runexp()" class="btn2 btn-exp">EXP</button>
        <button name="eq" value="=" onClick="runeq()" class="btn2 btn-eq">=</button>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    function run1()
     {document.calc.output.value += "1";}
    function run2()
     {document.calc.output.value += "2";}
    function run3()
     {document.calc.output.value += "3";}
    function run4()
     {document.calc.output.value += "4";}
    function run5()
     {document.calc.output.value += "5";}
    function run6()
     {document.calc.output.value += "6";}
    function run7()
     {document.calc.output.value += "7";}
    function run8()
     {document.calc.output.value += "8";}
    function run9()
     {document.calc.output.value += "9";}
    function run0()
         {document.calc.output.value += "0";}
    function rundec()
     {document.calc.output.value = ".";}
    function runplus()
     {document.calc.output.value = "+";}
    function runminus()
     {document.calc.output.value = "-";}
    function rundiv()
     {document.calc.output.value = "÷";}
    function runmulti()
     {document.calc.output.value = "x";}
    function rundel()
     {document.calc.output.value = "";}
</script>
```

when i click on any key, it's just blinking, how to solve it. and help me if there are other ways to build a calculator using javascript.

Comment: It would be great if you provide fiddle- jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the reason it's not working is that the element is in a `form`, it looks like it's submitting the form when you click the button. You can avoid this by doing:

```
onClick="run1(); return false;"
```

(and repeating it on all the buttons, or see that answer from **dbrin**)

Having said that, it's better not to make it a `form` at all, just have a surrounding `div` so your code starts like:

```
<div id='calc'>    
    <div class="screen">
        <input id="output" class="editscreen"/>
    </div>
    <div class="main-keys">
```

(note I've changed `name=` to `id=`) then you can use [`document.getElementById(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) to get the value:

```
function run2() {
    document.getElementById('output').value += "2";    
}
```

Finally you have a lot of duplication there, there's no need to have all the `runX` functions and it'll make life difficult when you need to change something in all of them. So look for ways to make it easier, as a start I'd look at:

```
function addDigit(digit) {  
    document.getElementById('output').value += digit;     
}
```

and then call it like:

```
<button name="2" value="2" onClick="addDigit(2)" class="btn2 num">2</button>
```

etc.

Now, instead of doing that you can go even more general. Inside of passing a literal digit into the function you can use the click event itself, then in the handler function (`addDigit`) you can click the button itself (it's the target of the event) and then get the `value` of that -- which is already set to the digit to be added. Doing that you can massively reduce the code above. You can look here for some background: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html and then this answer provides an example: [Javascript click event handler - how do I get the reference to the clicked item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846268/javascript-onclick-event-handler-how-do-i-get-the-reference-to-the-clicked-ite) -- that should start you off.

Comment: That looks cool, I think you'll be able to get it to work by going down the path you're going. It is worth considering trying reuse functions that are doing similar things as I show above. If you run into other problems you can always ask another question, show what you've tried and explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, that looks cool, i followed What you said and now how to perform those operations (+,-,=)

Answer (score 2):

Your form is getting submitted. 
Add this to the form element to prevent submission:

```
<form name="calc" onSubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: how can i perform math operations (+,-,= etc), using getElementByid... i want to use div not input or button tags.

Comment: different question, feel free to accept this one and ask another.