# Can't register change handler for radio button inside a <label> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on an ASP.NET MVC project. Due to the limitations of one of the components which I am working with, my radio buttons need to be placed inside label tags. However, when I am attempting to register a change handler on said radio buttons, the handler is never called. A cursory glance at similar questions has left me hanging.

Here is the JavaScript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=registrationType]").click(function() {
        alert("It works!");
    });
});
```

And here is the relevant cshtml:

```
<div class="radio">
    <label for="registrationType1">@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.registrationType, "type1", new { @id = "registrationType1", @required = "required" }) Option 1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label for="registrationType2">@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.registrationType, "type2", new { @id = "registrationType2", @required = "required" }) Option 2</label>    
</div>
```

My question is, what changes can I make to the jQuery code to register the change handler? Taking the radio button out of the label is not an option, unfortunately, as I know this would solve the problem immediately.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: As requested, here is the rendered HTML:

```
<div class="radio">
    <label for="registrationType1"><input class="registrationType" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please indicate your registration type" id="registrationType1" name="registrationType" required="required" type="radio" value="type1" /> Option 1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label for="registrationType2"><input class="registrationType" id="registrationType2" name="registrationType" required="required" type="radio" value="type2" />Option 2</label>    
</div>
```

Comment: I'll post the rendered HTML in a moment. I have tried it with the radio button outside of the label tag, and it works fine.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Razor or whatever syntax that is, but where are you actually putting the name attribute on those inputs? Would help to see the actual HTML being output.

Comment: Plus, `label` holds the name of a field (so, a string), not the field itself :) Your radio button should not be within `<label></label>`.

Comment: @lesssugar, I understand completely, and I'm not happy about having to do it. But I am required, due to the front end framework, to have them set up this way.

Comment: OK, as said before, show us the HTML rendered with your ASP code, and check the console for errors.

Comment: have you tried invoking it with the id (`#registrationType1`) or the class (`.registrationType`)?

Comment: @lesssugar, it has been added to the question.

Comment: Seems to work. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/kve7qgb0/. Make sure jQuery is loaded before you run the script. Take a look at console log for errors.

Comment: @AminJafari, yes, I have tried both.

Comment: I am certain that jQuery is loaded, as other jQuery functionality is not affected. I looked through the console log, with no success. I'm beginning to think it's my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to put the event handler on a parent element (such as a `<div>` that surrounds all of the radio buttons). You can then detect the specific element clicked by checking the `event` object's `target` property. This also has the advantage of requiring only one event handler to be set, which can sometimes be easier to code and better for memory management.

More details about checking the `target` property (including some IE compatibility) here: [Javascript click event handler - how do I get the reference to the clicked item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846268/javascript-onclick-event-handler-how-do-i-get-the-reference-to-the-clicked-ite)

And a handy explanation of why putting the event handler on a parent even works in the first place here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: I will try this out tomorrow when I get in. Thanks!