# How do I get button's ID from a list of buttons?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, button

I haven't worked much with php and javascript and was hoping to get some help. I want to be able to detect which button was clicked exactly. I'm creating one button per row but I don't know how to figure out what row the click was made in. This is what I have so far...

```
    # Get all the table data from the database
$getData = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `query_table`") or die ("Error occured while selecting!");

// echo '<form method="post" action="index.php">';
echo '<table border="1">';

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>Questions</td>';
echo '<td>Likes</td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '</tr>';

# Loop through each row and print out the question
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getData)) {
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
            echo $row['Question'];
        echo '</td>';

        echo '<td>';
            echo $row['Likes'];
        echo '</td>';

        echo '<td>';
        ?>

            <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Like" onclick="myFunc(<?=$row['ID']?>)" />

        <?php
        echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
// echo '</form>';
echo '<p id="text"></p>';

mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunc(id) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = id;
}
</script>
```

So far this prints out the row id where the button was clicked, but I don't suppose I can assign that parameter value directly to a php variable that I can then use for mysql queries. How is stuff like this normally done, please help.

Comment: so, the button is only one and need to check if LIKE and Question is clicked?

Comment: unrelated: `id`s on objects must be unique. you are giving every button the same id with `id="myButton"` - you should either not give them an id, or make sure they are unique (eg `id="myButton_<?= i ?>"` where i is an incrementing counter of some sort)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript onclick event handler - how do I get the reference to the clicked item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846268/javascript-onclick-event-handler-how-do-i-get-the-reference-to-the-clicked-ite)

Comment: To "assign the value to a PHP variable" you would need to make another call to the server, either via AJAX or a standard GET/POST request.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" data-id="<?=$row['ID']?>" value="Like" onclick="myFunc(this)">
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunc(button) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = button.getAttribute('data-id');
}
</script>
```

In JavaScript the token "this" refers to the context in which the code is running which in this case is the button. Store custom data in attributes prefixed with data- to ensure they are not disturbed - standard practise.