# Share singleton in its own method AND the current element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, singleton

I'm trying to make my jQuery code more readable and easier to maintain.

Here's what I have :

```
var module = {
    init: function () {
        this.domElement       = $('#dom_element');
        this.secondDomElement = $('#second_dom_element');
        this.okElement        = 'ok';
        this.events();
    },

    events: function () {
        this.domElement.on('click', $.proxy(this.alertOk, this));
        this.secondDomElement.on('click', $.proxy(this.alertOkAndItSelf, this));
    },

    alertOk: function () {
        alert(this.okElement);
    },

    alertOkAndItSelf: function () {
        alert(this.okElement + ' ' + $(this)); // $(this) != $('#second_dom_element') !
    }
};
```

So when module.domElement is clicked, that works fine. 'ok' is in the alert.

But when module.secondElement is clicked, 'ok' is in the alert, but then $(this) is still referencing the module.
If I don't use $.proxy, then this is the current element, but how do I access the okElement property of module ?

I feel like using module.okElement to access it is kind of dirty.

Comment: Why not use the click-event to retrieve the event target? see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846268/javascript-click-event-handler-how-do-i-get-the-reference-to-the-clicked-item

Comment: Yes that works fine !! Thanks a lot man ! Here's the fiddle ! https://jsfiddle.net/s3yx9k0w/1/

Comment: Great that worked :)